# Command executed in busybox shell script gives no output

Tags: shell, sh, busybox, gentoo, ash

I boot my computer with initramfs that I have generated with gentoo genkernel. I now tweak and update initramfs filesystem and kernel by hand for more flexibility.
I tried to update busybox as the newer version has more functionalities, from
**v1.20.2** generated by genkernel to **v1.25.1** in my main gentoo system.
I get the following problem that I am unable to solve

```
#!/bin/busybox sh
blkid -U 4b714b37-3590-48e9-8866-465d9e6726f2e
```

gives no output while

```
#!/bin/sh
blkid -U 4b714b37-3590-48e9-8866-465d9e6726f2e
```

gives /dev/sda4 as expected.

Thank you very much for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that busybox blkid does not recognize -U option and do not output any error message. I solved my problem invoking blkid without any argument and parsing the output manually.

```
blkid | grep 4b714b37-3590-48e9-8866-465d9e6726f2e | cut -d ":" -f1
```